# cfspreadsheet is reading empty string when columns are specified

Tags: string, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I have tried to read an xlsx file with the usage of cfspreadsheet and dump it on the webpage.

Code:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="<!--- file directory --->" 
    query="Result" 
    sheet="1"  
    rows="1-4" 
    columns="1-3" 
    headerRow="1" 
    excludeHeaderRow = "true"> 

<cfdump var="#Result#">
```

cfspreadsheet manages to read the rows correctly, but not the columns. After reading the first three columns, the rest of the columns appears as empty strings, like this:

```
   Name   Pet    Tag   col_10           col_11           col_12        ...col_28 
1  John   Woody  E3D   [empty string]   [empty string]  [empty string] 
2  Jane   Worm   E7A   [empty string]   [empty string]  [empty string] 
3  Jake   Worky  E3Q   [empty string]   [empty string]  [empty string]
```

How can I solve the issue above?

*Edit: The data source format:

```
    Name   Pet      Tag      Email                     first tag          second tag       .third tag       ds2_det
1  John   Woody  E3D     derp@gmail.com   R23DE5EW    R23DE5EW      R23DE5EW  R286gdegj.*<te>
2  Jane   Worm   E7A    ....                          .....                  .....                     .....
3  Jake   Worky  E3Q      ........                      ....                   ....                     .......
```

Comment: This may be due the fact that you have set the `columns` attribute to "1-3".

Comment: Can you share the Source file least 3rows data. I never faced any issue while restricting columns.

Comment: @Ramki Obviously I want to only show 3 columns of data. I don't need the [empty string] and the rest of the columns.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I did not test the above) Agreed, most would expect the query to return only three columns, but .. can you be more specific about the problem it is causing in your code? Since you already know the columns you need, is there a reason you can't just reference the columns you need by name ( or index using `getMetaData(query)` ), and ignore the rest?